# FusionCharts in Codeigniter Error: FusionCharts is not defined

Tags: codeigniter, fusioncharts

Hello all I am trying to use fusion charts in Codeigniter. I just followed the instruction from 
http://www.ikawka.com/2008/12/fusion-chart/comment-page-1/

I see the error

> "FusionCharts is not defined"

in firebug. On the view page I only see

> "Chart."

Plugin folder has the file named fusion_pi.php

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');  
function FusionCharts( $chart_type='Column3D', $width = "300", $height = "250" ){  
    require_once('fusion/FusionCharts_Gen.php' );  
    $FC = new FusionCharts($chart_type,$width,$height);  
    $FC->setSWFPath("images/fusioncharts/");  
    return $FC;  
}  
?>
```

Controller:

```
function index()
 {

  // echo "hello world";
  $this->load->view("jquery_view");


$this->load->plugin( 'fusion' );  
echo "hi";
$FC =  FusionCharts("Column3D","520","200");  
$arrData = array( 500, 269, 254, 895, 633);  
foreach( $arrData as $i=>$data ){  
    $FC->addChartData( $data );  
}  
$strParam="numberSuffix=%; formatNumberScale=0; decimalPrecision=0; xAxisName=Integrated Process Average Score; animation=1";  
$FC->setChartParams($strParam);  
$FC->setChartMessage("ChartNoDataText=Chart Data not provided; PBarLoadingText=Please Wait.The chart is loading...");  
echo $FC->renderChart();  


 }
```

View:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/FusionCharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/ajax.js" ></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php echo "Rajani". base_url()."js/FusionCharts.js";?>
        <label for="name">UserName</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" />
        <input type="password" id="pwd" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</body>
</html>
```

I found that the line in view file: js/FusionCharts.js"> 
is not detecting. What might be the problem? 
Need Help.

Thanks.

Comment: code? would be nice to take a look at it...

Comment: Just added code. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, try:

```
function index()
 {
$this->load->plugin( 'fusion' );  
$FC =  FusionCharts("Column3D","520","200");  
$arrData = array( 500, 269, 254, 895, 633);  
foreach( $arrData as $i=>$data ){  
    $FC->addChartData( $data );  
}  
$strParam="numberSuffix=%; formatNumberScale=0; decimalPrecision=0; xAxisName=Integrated Process Average Score; animation=1";  
$FC->setChartParams($strParam);  
$FC->setChartMessage("ChartNoDataText=Chart Data not provided; PBarLoadingText=Please Wait.The chart is loading...");  
$data['chart'] = $FC->renderChart();  

$this->load->view("jquery_view", $data);
 }
```

On your view, try:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/FusionCharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/ajax.js" ></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <? echo $chart; ?>

        <label for="name">UserName</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" />
        <input type="password" id="pwd" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is giving error in controller $data['chart'] = $FC->renderChart(); : " Error Message: Cannot use a scalar value as an array"

Comment: @Raj, you are using the plugin wrong. Please refer back to the http://www.ikawka.com/2008/12/fusion-chart/comment-page-1/ , and follow the steps again.